# How do you run one XCTestCase subclass's test method from inside another XCTestCase subclass's test method in XCode 7?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xcode7, xctest

How do you run one XCTestCase subclass's test method from inside another XCTestCase subclass's test method in XCode 7?

I have a test suite for my point-of-sale app.

I have an XCTestCase subclass called "MathTest" which does various unit tests on math functions of the app. It also has a test method **testTillMath** that checks the register to see if the transaction totals all match up to expected values.

Then I have another XCTestCase subclass called "TicketBuildingTest" which has a test method called **testCreateTickets** that draws from an Excel spreadsheet data source, using whatever data is in the spreadsheet to assemble a specific batch of transactions into a special Core Data store specific to the test environment.

The **testTillMath** method will only succeed if **testCreateTickets** has first been run successfully.

How can I make **testTillMath** get run every time after **testCreateTickets** has finished?

I tried to `#include MathTest.m` from inside of TicketBuildingTest so that I could call **testTillMath** at the end of **testCreateTickets**, but XCode won't let me do that include. The build fails with the error, "linker command failed with exit code 1" due to "duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MathTest"

I realize there is likely to be more than one way to skin this cat; in PHPUnit I can specify a set of test methods to be run all in a row, in a certain order, running each test after the one before it completes. How can I do that in XCode?

Comment: In my opinion, test should be as independent from each other as possible. Apart from that, I don't think this is possible out of the box. Maybe you can try to create a common super class an put the common tests in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've deliberately introduced "test pollution", i.e. a situation where the success or failure of one test is dependent on the success or failure of another test. This is a bad practice. Tests should be independent of each other. That way you know that when a test fails, it's failing due to the functionality within your app that it's specifically testing—so you can track down that functionality and fix it. Debugging test pollution is a real ordeal, and you should avoid it at all costs.

Some testing frameworks ([Rspec](http://rspec.info), for one; [Cedar](https://github.com/pivotal/cedar) for another) randomize the order in which tests are run, precisely to discourage the kind of test coupling you describe.

Comment: Your answer is correct, since I called them unit tests. Unit tests absolutely should not depend on each other. That being said, as it turns out, I was not writing unit tests, but in fact, I was writing an [end-to-end test](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/7035/end-to-end-test). We ended up using a sequence of four independent tests where the subsequent tests depend on the previous tests to set up the database in a particular way (through a series of simulated UI interactions). That's not to say end-to-end tests are better than unit tests. We also have those too.

Comment: I was able to make the tests in the end-to-end test run sequentially by alphabetizing the method names. However in XCode 8, it appears to randomize the order of test execution. I'm guessing that's intended by them, based on what you're saying about Rspec and Cedar. That's OK, we can just make our end-to-end test fit under one giant test method. It was useful to see each section pass independently, but we can just put an XCTFail at the critical junctures and have the same effect.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix your problem! I take issue, though, with one thing you say in your comment: "a sequence of four independent tests where the subsequent tests depend on the previous tests". If subsequent tests depend on previous tests, then by definition they are not independent—which is what caused your trouble in the first place. I'm a big fan of your solution, btw; I often try to consolidate my end-to-end tests into one big so-called "journey" test.